# HttpPost controller parameters null ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, http-post

I am writing a javascript function for a **button on a modal dialog**. The code for the button is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" id="clone" onclick="clone(null, @Model.Id,@Model.CloneId)">Clone</button>
```

I have an **onclick function** for when the button is clicked:

```
function clone(e, Id, CloneId) {

var valuesetName = $("#newValueSet").val();

var data = JSON.stringify({ 'id': Id, 'cloneId': CloneId, 'newValueSet': valuesetName });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Tests/Clone',
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    success: function () { }
});

}
```

The **ActionMethod** is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Clone([FromBody]EditModel model)
{
    //logic
}
```

The **model class** is:

```
public class EditModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CloneId { get; set; }
    public string ValueSetName { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to Debug this code, the AJAX function gets the values correctly, but does not pass them to the ActionMethod. What could be the reason for this? Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core 3? `ValueSetName` won't bind, because you use `newValueSet` on the JSON, so the name doesn't match. It's _possible_ you might be sending strings for `Id` and `CloneId`, which would also fail. I'm just guessing though...

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes, changing the json data to match the names in the EditModel passed the values.. Thank you! :)

Answer (score -2):

From Ms Docs:

> Using [FromBody]
> To force Web API to read a **simple** type from the request body, add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter

what that means that if you are using FromBody you can only pass **primitive** parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CloneValues([FromBody]string text)
{
    //logic
}
```

What you need is FromUri

> Using [FromUri]
> To force Web API to read a **complex** type from the URI, add the [FromUri] attribute to the parameter. The following example defines a GeoPoint type, along with a controller method that gets the GeoPoint from the URI.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CloneValues([FromUri]EditModel model)
{
    //logic
}
```

Comment: To add [FromUri] Visual Studio asked me to install a package, which I did but now it's creating an ambiguous reference for **[HttpPost]** and the error says, _'HttpPost' is an ambiguous reference between **System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute** and **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute**_

Comment: you can type [System.Web.Http.FromUri] instead of just [FromUri] to get past the ambiguous reference

Comment: @VertexGames I am still not getting any values in the actionMethod

Comment: Maybe try to change the names in the ajax quary to match the names in the object? Id instead of id,CloneId instead of cloneid..
you get the point..i think its case sens